# Syntax for BluetoothLEDevice::RequestPreferredConnectionParameters()

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

Using C++/WinRT, Win10, VS2019, SDK 10.0.22621.0, NuGet CppWinRT 2.0.220608.4

I'm trying to get the `RequestPreferredConnectionParameters` to work.  At this point I am wondering if maybe I have the syntax wrong or maybe something else about it that I am not aware of. The MS docs for the function are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice.requestpreferredconnectionparameters?view=winrt-22621) and the link to the various parameters are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothlepreferredconnectionparameters?view=winrt-22621).

The command line, as I have it, with pubDevice being the BLE device object, is:

```
BluetoothLEPreferredConnectionParametersRequest rcoConnect = pubDevice.RequestPreferredConnectionParameters(BluetoothLEPreferredConnectionParameters::ThroughputOptimized());
```

Just to mention, I am able to run

```
auto statusTest = co_await pubDevice.RequestAccessAsync();
```

before the `RequestPreferredConnectionParameters` without problems so, obviously, the device object is good and can be connected to.

What is happening is this.  I have a function, OpenDevice(), that opens the device based on the address.  If, after getting the device object, I issue the command above while still in the OpenDevice function, the code will not crash but it will immediately jump to the end of the OpenDevice() function bypassing all other lines of code below it and there will be no connection at all after that.

If I run the `RequestPreferredConnectionParameters` outside of the OpenDevice() function it errors out with a
`An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback` and the line referenced is in `base.h line 4942 if (result == impl::error_changed_state)`

I had assumed that the callback refered to was the Rx Characteristic ValueChanged Callback that is set in OpenDevice(). So I tested by first revoking that callback with

```
pubRxCharacteristic.ValueChanged(etValueChangeToken);
```

and then running the `RequestPreferredConnectionParameters` but I still got the `An unhandled exception` error.

The only other callback that I have is the `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` advert received callback but that was stopped after the device was found.

Can anyone verify that my syntax seems correct and/or have any clue as to what is causing my problems?

**EDIT to show more code in a console app------------**
@IInspectable
Again for the record:
Using C++/WinRT, Win10, VS2019 - Console App, SDK 10.0.22621.0, NuGet CppWinRT 2.0.220608.4

Pertinent includes in the pch.h file:

```
// 2022/9/10 -- for WHCAR and apparently GUID
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <winrt\Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Storage.Streams.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Advertisement.h>
#include <winrt\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.GenericAttributeProfile.h>
// 2022/9/10
#include <winrt\Windows.Devices.Enumeration.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
```

Pertinent name spaces at top of Main.cpp:

```
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::Storage::Streams;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Bluetooth;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::Advertisement;
using namespace Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile;
// 2022/9/10 for RequestConnectionAsync
using namespace Windows::Devices::Enumeration;
```

I assume that the code to watch for and find the device is not pertinent here.  Needless to say the device is found and the address is passed to OpenDevice to create the device object.

Here is the top portion of OpenDevice:

```
IAsyncAction OpenDevice(unsigned long long deviceAddress)
{
    auto device = co_await BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(deviceAddress);

    // 2022/9/10 test code
    auto statusTest = co_await device.RequestAccessAsync();
    // Allowed, DeniedBySystem, Unspecified
    if (statusTest != DeviceAccessStatus::Allowed) {            
        std::cout << "Access to device is not allowed...." << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Access to device is allowed...." << std::endl;
    }

    // Next line ends without error but immediately goes to the end of OpenDevice()
    std::cout << "Asking for ThroughputOptimized...." << std::endl;
    auto statusConnection = device.RequestPreferredConnectionParameters(BluetoothLEPreferredConnectionParameters::ThroughputOptimized());
    std::cout << "Line after Request ThroughputOptimized...." << std::endl;
    Beep(500, 500);<br/> // function never gets to this cout or Beep<br/>
// More code follows to get Rx and TxCharacteristics etc.<br/>
} // end OpenDevice
```

Here is the console output:
Notice the last cout is the line `Asking for ThroughputOptimized`.
No cout for `Line after Request ThroughputOptimized` and no `Beep`.

> Trying to locate the TENS device: Waiting for device:
> AdvertisementReceived:
> LocalName: []
> AdvertisementType: [ConnectableUndirected]
> BluetoothAddress: [0x300000e59630]
> RawSignalStrengthInDBm: [-60] ServiceUUID:  [0000fff0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb]
>   Found TENS Device Main
> Service....
>  TENS device found. Access to device is
> allowed....
>  Asking for ThroughputOptimized....
>
> WinRTBle.exe (process 15576) exited with code -1073740791.
>   Press
> any key to close this window .

Barring a problem in syntax or a missing header. the only other thing that I can think of is that it needs Win11.  The docs for RequestPreferredConnectionParameters Method say

> Windows requirements Device family    Windows 11 (introduced in
> 10.0.22000.0)

Does that mean that regardless of the SDK it needs Win11?

Comment: A description of code will usually omit the part that's wrong. By contrast, a [mcve] won't. That's required (a console application is probably sufficient).

Comment: @IInspectable let me put this into the original console test app and I will update this post.  Right now it is in an MFC app.

Comment: *"Does that mean that regardless of the SDK it needs Win11?"* - Yes. Functionality that gets added in a specific Windows release is only available in that release (and later ones). The SDK used never makes a difference (other than not offering features introduced in versions of Windows later than the  SDK version).

Comment: That is what I feared.  I've been chasing this function in the hope that it would speed up the reaction time between when the write command was sent and the shock from the TENS device was felt.  My next step is the bracket for Win11 and then compile my main MFC app into an exe and run that in the VM Win11 and see what timing difference there really is.  Then all I can do is wait for the slow migration of my users to Win11.  I guess that I will have to think of doing the same thing eventually.

Comment: That sounds like the only way forward. Not very attractive, but that's how it needs to be done. At least the Windows Runtime allows you to perform feature queries at run time so that you only have to maintain a single source base, and can ship a single binary, where features "light up" on systems that support them. [Version adaptive apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-apps) explains how to do this.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for this reference.  Once I test this on Win11 I'm going to have to go this the referenced article and make sure I make the proper adjustments.  And, of course, test on my other lower end and older machines.

Answer (score 0):

@IInspectable As much as I was dreading this, apparently the answer is that it needs Win11.  The console app code mentioned above in the edit to the original question was compiled into an exe.  I have Win11 on a VM VirtualBox and I ran that exe on that Win11 and the code continued past the `ThroughputOptimized()` line in question and finished the rest of the app as expected.  So that's ashamed.  I don't have Win11 on a real box yet (call me paranoid) but I guess I could bracket the code for the Win11 OS and only run it when a user happens to be running Win11

Always something.......

**EDIT 2 ...............................**
And the "Always something" comes up immediately.  As far as I can tell from what I have been able to find, there is no way to tell if the OS is Win10 or Win11.  It was recommended to use RtlGetVersion but that returned 10 for both Win10 and Win11.  Another poster suggested to use the File version of the System32 kernal32.dll file but they also both reported major number 10 and minor number 0.  The MS docs for adding a version manifest had the UUIDs for both OSs as the same.

This is ridiculous that MS would come up with a function that only runs in Win11 and then not have to ability to tell you which OS you are running in....Jeeeeeeze.....

**EDIT 3.........................**
Spoke too soon.  I was messing around with the console app and forgot that in my MFC app I use the `WMI IWbemClassObject Caption property` to get the OS.
For Windows 10 I get
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
and for Win11 I get
Microsoft Windows 11 Home
So apparently that is really the only way to do it.